# Sum up each row of database sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to sum up each row of data in one column of  database table. How do I do that?
Here's the pieces of code of my sqlite database

```
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PENGELUARAN =
         "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + PENGELUARAN_TABLE + " (" +
                  KEY_RPI + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                  KEY_RTP + "," +
                  KEY_RLP + "," +
                  KEY_RSK + "," +
                  KEY_RNP + ");";
```

I want to sum up the data in each row of KEY_RNP column. I think it can be used by using array but can anyone give me the exact code? Sorry for my bad english. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for the sql? `select sum(field_name) from table_name` or how to execute and return the result?

Comment: yea well, what data type is that function work for? The data in KEY_RNP row are string formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite [sum()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(column) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in SQL that does want you want, called `SUM()`.

Call it like this:

SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE ...;

Comment: So is that means If the data type I have in KEY_RNP column is String, I should convert it first?

Comment: That's right. You can use SQLite cast for this: `SELECT SUM(CAST(column as INTEGER)) FROM table;`